# Finitely generated module over formal power series can be transformed in a free module.

Tags: modules, formal-power-series

If $M$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}[[ t]]$-module, I have to show that there exists a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t^nM$ is a free $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$-module. I have no idea how I can start with this proof so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start with a set of generators $g_1,...,g_n$. If there is a linear relation $s_1g_1+...+s_ng_n=0$, let's assume (without loss of generality) that $s_1\neq0$. Then $s_1=t^{k_1}a_1$ with $a_1$ invertible. Then $t^{k_1}M$ can be generated by $t^{k_1}g_1,...,t^{k_1}g_n$, but actually the previous relation gives $t^{k_1}g_1=-a_1^{-1}s_2t^{k_1}g_2-...-a_1^{-1}t^{k_1}g_n$. So, $t^{k_1}M$ can be generated by $t^{k_1}g_2,...,t^{k_1}g_n$. Keep going. If there is a linear relation between them do the same process to eliminate one of the generators with non-zero coefficient.

Comment: Do you know the classification of finitely generated modules over a PID?

Comment: @conditionalMethod I don't see how we get that $t^{k_1}g_1 = -a_1^{-1}(s_2t^{k_1}g_2+...+s_nt^{k_1}g_n)$, I only get that $t^{k_1}g_1 = -a_1^{-1}(s_2g_2+...+s_ng_n)$, so it's not necessarily generated by $t^{k_1}g_2,...,t^{k_1}g_n$

Comment: That's right. My argument is not correct. We need to write each non-zero $s_k=t^{m_k}a_k$ with $s_k$ invertible. Then look at the minimum $m = min(m_k)$, assume $m=m_{k_1}$, and express the corresponding $g_{1}=-a_1^{-1}(s_2t^{m_2-m}g_2+...+s_nt^{m_n-m}g_n)$. So, switching to $t^{min(m_k-m)}M$ one can get rid of the generator $g_1$ and generate the entire module $t^{min(m_k-m)}M$ with $t^{min(m_k-m)}g_2,...,t^{min(m_k-m)}g_n$. If there is a further non-trivial linear relation with these then we repeat the same process to eliminate one more by in a further multiple of $M$ by a power of $t$.